# Почему не могу сгенерировать словари такими генераторами

Tags: python, python-3.x, словари, синтаксис, генераторы

Почему не могу сгенерировать словари такими генераторами?

```
D = { k: v for (k, v) in zip(range[-4], range[4])}

D = { k: v for (k, v) in zip(range(-4), range(4))}

D = { k: v for (k, v) in zip(range[-4, 4], range[-7, 1])}
```

а такой генерирует

```
D = { k: v for (k, v) in zip(range(4), range(4))}
```

Comment: D = { k: v for (k, v) in zip(range(-4), range(4))} - а здесь почему выдает пустыми словарь?

Comment: Потому что `range(-4) == range(0, -4, 1)` - пустой список получается

Comment: благодарю за помощь

Answer (score 1):

Потому что `range` - это такой специальный тип (класс) (в Python 2 это встроенная функция), который не поддерживает индексирования (класс, в котором не реализован метод `__getitem__()`).

```
In [148]: type(range)
Out[148]: type

In [149]: type(int)
Out[149]: type
```

такую же ошибку вы получите попытавшись индексировать другие встроенные типы (например `int`):

```
In [150]: int[0]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-150-c0b83255530b> in <module>()
----> 1 int[0]

TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
```

Существует более лаконичная версия:

```
In [1]: dict(zip(range(4), range(4)))
Out[1]: {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3}
```

или

```
In [7]: dict(zip(range(-4, 0), range(4)))
Out[7]: {-4: 0, -3: 1, -2: 2, -1: 3}
```

---

По поводу использования функции (в Python 3 - конструктора) `range()`:

```
In [155]: range?
Init signature: range(self, /, *args, **kwargs)
Docstring:
range(stop) -> range object
range(start, stop[, step]) -> range object

Return an object that produces a sequence of integers from start (inclusive)
to stop (exclusive) by step.  range(i, j) produces i, i+1, i+2, ..., j-1.
start defaults to 0, and stop is omitted!  range(4) produces 0, 1, 2, 3.
These are exactly the valid indices for a list of 4 elements.
When step is given, it specifies the increment (or decrement).
Type:           type
```

Т.е. при вызове с одним аргументом вы указываете конец последовательности, которая начинается с нуля...

Очевидно, что:

```
0 ... -4
```

вернет пустую последовательность

Comment: D = { k: v for (k, v) in zip(range(4), range(4))} - а это генератор спокойно формирует словарь, чего?

Comment: не понял вопрос - словарь чего формируется или почему это работает?

Comment: он формерует заполненый словарь, а если сменить на -4 и 4 (4 и -4) то формерует пустой словарь, чего так?

Comment: благодарю за помощь

Answer (score 1):

По 1 и 3 случаям: `range` - это функция, а к функциям неприменим оператор "квадратные скобки". Функцию можно вызвать с параметрами в круглых скобках (например, `range(-4, 4)`, но не `range[-4, 4]`)

По случаю с одиночным отрицательным параметром: `range(n)` создает **возрастающую** последовательность от 0 до n (n не входит в последовательность). Если n отрицательно, то это будет пустая последовательность. Вам скорее всего нужно или `range(-4, 0)` (будет последовательность чисел от -4 до -1 включительно), или `range(0, -4, -1)` (убывающая последовательность от 0 до -3).

Comment: благодарю за помощь!